# Number theory: divisors of $|2016^m - 36^n|$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $N$ be a natural number and $p$ be the number of its divisors. If we know that $N =|2016^m - 36^n| $, what is the minimum number $p$ if $m$ and $n$  are natural numbers ($m,n > 0$)?

Comment: Note: $2016 = 2^5 \times 3^2 \times 7$

Comment: Do you count $0$ as a natural?

Comment: I don't count $0$ as a natural number

Comment: I don't see how that matters.

Comment: Oh, I swear I have misread it as $N=|2016^m-36^m|$...

Comment: Definitely $\min p\le30$ because $2016-36^2=720$, and we know that $720$ has only $30$ divisors.

Comment: The minimum looks like $12$, achieved by $2016-36=1980$. I think it is straightforward to show this is optimal because every numbers of the form divides $180$.

Comment: @didgogns $1980$ has 36 divisors.

Comment: 1980 has 36 divisors:

Comment: Oh why I thought it had 12 divisors?

Comment: We also know that $\min p \ge 9$ because $\gcd(2016,36)=36$, and $36$ has $9$ divisors.

Comment: I noticed that $4, 5, 9 |  N$ so $N = 2^2 * 3^2 * 5 * k$ where k is a natural. Now we know that $N$ has at least 18 divisors($k = 1$).

Comment: But we cannot say that $\min p = 18$ because we don't know if $k$ can be equal to $1$

Comment: But k being equal to 1 tells you exactly what N is. I suppose some result from number theory should tell you that for large n,m you will never get such small gaps.

Comment: After searching with a computer, I conjecture that $\min p = 30$.

Comment: I just want to say that this was a problem on a Junior Serbian Mathematical Olympiad last year(for 14 to 15 year olds). Apparently i can't find the solution anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know the answer is at most $30$ since $2016-36^2=720$ has $30$ divisors. I will prove it is optimal.

It is trivial to see that for any integer $k$, if $k$ divides $N$ then $N$ has same or more divisors than $k$.

Firstly, $5$ always divides $N$. And if $\min(m,n)\ge 2$, then $36^2=2^43^4|N$. Therefore, $N$ has at least $50$ divisors (from $2^43^45$). We can exclude this case and suppose that $m=1$ or $n=1$.

i) $m=1$: For $n<3$, we can check manually that there are no $N$ with less than $30$ divisors. For $n \ge 3$, we can see that $1440=2^53^25|N$ so $N$ has at least $36$ divisors.

ii) $n=1$: $180=2^23^25|N$, so $N$ has at least $18$ divisors. If there is another prime factor of $N$, we are done. Let's suppose that there are no other prime factor of $N$, and also $m>1$ (we can check $m=1$ case manually).

We can observe that since $2^3|2016^m$ and $2^3$ does not divide $36$, $2^3$ does not divide $N$. Similarly, $3^3$ does not divide $N$. For $N$ to have less than or equal to $30$ divisors, $N \le 2^23^25^3=4500$ and some calculation shows that this is impossible.

Therefore, we can conclude that $p=30$.

Comment: Your  (iii) doesn't follow. 720 **is** divisible by 180, yet has less than 36 divisors.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I will fix it.

Comment: The first sentence "the answer is at least 30" should be "the answer is at most 30"

Comment: This is the same approach I was writing up but you were faster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i suspect there might be an easier solution to this problem which doesn't include so much manual checking or maybe an optimised one. I will try to find it now

Comment: I think that in this solution you missed that 5 always divides $N$ which lowers the number of manual checkings by a big margin.

Comment: Yes, I will try that.